# Casting an object from a stack

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Why does this:

```
System.Collections.Stack s = new Stack();
s.Push(97);
char c = (char) s.Pop(); //throws InvalidCastException
```

throw an error, but this:

```
char c = (char) 97; //c = 'a'
```

work just fine?

I'm especially confused since `s.Pop().GetType()` returns `System.Int32`, so it really shouldn't matter...
What's going on here? Am I missing something, or do I have to work around it?

Comment: `s.Push((char)97);`?

Comment: I wonder why are you even using something from the `System.Collections` namespace instead of `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: @RubensFarias yeah, I could do that in this example, but not in the context of the thing I'm programming. This is massively simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Stack` is the non-generic variant of a stack implementation. `Pop` returns an `object`, and the cast `object -> char` is invalid.

This does work though:

```
char c = (char)(int)s.Pop();
```

My two cents: use a generic implementation of `Stack`:

```
`Stack<char> s = new Stack<char>();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic version of `Stack<T>` like

```
Stack<int> s = new Stack<int>();
s.Push(97);
char c = (char)s.Pop();
Console.WriteLine(c);
```